# Storing Shapes in database

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase

What is more effective? Storing Shapes as shape column (http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/topology_basics.htm) in database? Or maybe store shapes in seperate tables and join them?